# on logging into civi we are getting the following error message, can anyone direct me as to a solution?

Tags: drupal, siteground

Initialization Error

Array
(
[callback] => Array
(
[0] => CRM_Core_Error
[1] => simpleHandler
)

```
[code] => -24
[message] => DB Error: connect failed
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] =>  [nativecode=Access denied for user 'pascrm49_drupa86'@'localhost' to database 'pascrm49_civicrm']
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] =>  [nativecode=Access denied for user 'pascrm49_drupa86'@'localhost' to database 'pascrm49_civicrm']
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: connect failed" code=-24 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info=" [nativecode=Access denied for user 'pascrm49_drupa86'@'localhost' to database 'pascrm49_civicrm']"]
```

)
Initialization Error

Array
(
[callback] => Array
(
[0] => CRM_Core_Error
[1] => simpleHandler
)

```
[code] => -24
[message] => DB Error: connect failed
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] =>  [nativecode=Access denied for user 'pascrm49_drupa86'@'localhost' to database 'pascrm49_civicrm']
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] =>  [nativecode=Access denied for user 'pascrm49_drupa86'@'localhost' to database 'pascrm49_civicrm']
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: connect failed" code=-24 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info=" [nativecode=Access denied for user 'pascrm49_drupa86'@'localhost' to database 'pascrm49_civicrm']"]
```

)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need database access and grant all permissions to the user 'pascrm49_drupa86'@'localhost' for the 'pascrm49_civicrm' database.

Something like

grant all on 'pascrm49_civicrm' to 'pascrm49_drupa86'@'localhost';

Theres probably an official direction somewhere but this is just to get you out of a bind if your civicrm install is broken.

Comment: thanks, I couldn't find a way of altering the permissions. but I did a back up and restored a previous version which seems to have resolved the issue.